# French translation of "well-powered" category

Tags: terminology, category-theory, mathematical-french

In order to write a report, I'm looking for a French translation of the term "well-powered category".

Does anyone know the canonical term in French?

Comment: Catégorie pleine? http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9orie_des_cat%C3%A9gories

Comment: @user42912 No, that refers to "full subcategories".

Comment: @Pece In SGA 4 they seem to just say ‘l'ensemble des sous-objets de $X$ dans $C$ est petit’...

Comment: I think there's no french word for well-powered. After a few searches on Google, I found someone saying that the term "well-powered" is also used in french. Someone said he uses the word "bénépotente".

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes, I thought of SGA4 and did not find a specific term as you said.

Comment: @girianshiido Thanks. I think I'll just use "well-powered" so.

Comment: Why not asking a french mathematician directly?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I thought a french mathematician could be in the aera. However, I meet my advisor today about the report I write and I should have the answer (or not) by tonight.

Comment: Well, my advisor had no clue either. Thanks all of you anyway.